# Designing a linear time algorithm to check whether an n-vertex polygon is convex

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

And also i shouldn't assume that the polygon is non-intersecting

I know that a convex polygon is a non intersecting polygon with the property that all the angles are less than PI in another words , the orientation is always clockwise or anticlockwise.

So i am thinking to run the graham scan which is known to be a linear time algorithm and modify it .

SO here is my algorithm

```
we sort the vertices by orientation (using determinants)
Select the right most vertex in the Polygon P (call it r)
Let q and p be the next and second next vertex of Polygon P (based on orientation)
while(there is a vertex in the Polygon P)
  if orientation(p, q, r) == CW (clock wise , that means we changed directions)
     return false
  else
   r = p
   p = q
   q = next vertex
return true
```

is that algorithm accurate (returns false means its not convex)

Comment: You risk O(N log N) in your first line by sorting depending on the sorting algorithm used. Since you are interested in the max value, you should just find it directly by using a linear scan of the polygon points. The other two vertices can be found by moving to the left of the circular list of polygon vertices twice. Otherwise, the algorithm looks valid.

Comment: I'm also thinking you don't need to find the right most vertex. You can start with any vertex p, and just find the two vertices left and right of itjust move circularly one vertex at a time until you get to the point where that starting vertex p, is p once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, a check whether an angle is less or more than PI can be done in constant time using determinants.
This totals to O (N).

If all the angles have the same orientation, we should still check whether the polygon is also not self-intersecting.
Here, it will suffice to add up all supplementary angles and check whether the sum is 2 * PI.
It will be fine to use floating point and check for approximate equality.
This is also O (N).

However, we should visit the vertices in the order they follow on the polygon border.
If you are given a polygon, you perhaps have that order already.
On the other hand, if you are given just a set of points on the plane, a polygon with vertices in these points is not unique in the general case.
So, there is no need to sort the vertices by anything: not only it is O (N log N), but we also lose important order information by doing so.

We can start from any vertex.

Answer (score 0):

your algorithm does not work

(e.g. if the polygonal chain turns twice around the origin)

see http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00413179/en